# Filtering columns in txt file

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a csv file with 2 columns like

```
bob,red
bob,red
sam,blue
judy,black
sam,blue
nick,blue
judy,red
sam,blue
nick,red
don,red
judy,blue
```

Using bash in Ubuntu I need a filter to select only the rows where column one value appears multiple times but is matched with more than "X" number of values in column two.
So if "X" = 2 the result would be

```
judy,black
judy,red
judy,blue
nick,blue
nick,red
```

or if "X" = 3

```
judy,black
judy,red
judy,blue
```

Comment: why bob is not there when x=2?

Comment: because bob's column two is the same in all rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the output that **[@choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703141/filtering-columns-in-txt-file/15703636#15703636)** gives and not the output you ask for in the question but without all the extra pipes:

```
awk -F, -v x=3 '!a[$0]++{c[$1]++}END{for(k in c)if(c[k]>=x)print k,c[k]}' file 
judy 3

awk -F, -v x=2 '!a[$0]++{c[$1]++}END{for(k in c)if(c[k]>=x)print k,c[k]}' file 
judy 3
nick 2
```

Otherwise a solution for what you actually asked for:

```
awk -F, -v x=2 '!a[$0]++{c[$1]++;n[$1]?n[$1]=n[$1]"\n"$0:n[$1]=$0}END{for(k in c)if(c[k]>=x)print n[k]}' file
judy,black
judy,red
judy,blue
nick,blue
nick,red

awk -F, -v x=3 '!a[$0]++{c[$1]++;n[$1]?n[$1]=n[$1]"\n"$0:n[$1]=$0}END{for(k in c)if(c[k]>=x)print n[k]}' file
judy,black
judy,red
judy,blue
```

Comment: That works too but creates an extra blank line between the column one matches

Comment: @webtron see edit if you don't want the groups separated with a newline.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
sort -u 1.csv
```

to get rid of the repeating values. Then, you can count the number of occurrences of the column 1 values:

```
sort -u 1.csv | cut -f1 -d, | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Now, you can use `sed` to only select the correct numbers of occurrences:

```
sort -u 1.csv | cut -f1 -d, | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | sed -n '/ 2 /,$p'
```

The rest is left as an exercise for the reader.